# Changes in NHibernate 3.3

Tags: nhibernate, spatial, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm extending NHibernate.Spatial to use Oracle Spatial Dialect.
It used to work with NHibernate 3.1. Nowadays I'm trying to upgrade to NHibernate 3.3 however after fixing the compilation problems I get an Ora exception during the execution of the query

Query example:

```
var intersectingPolygonCount = session.QueryOver<Road>()
                                    .WhereSpatialRestrictionOn(x => x.Centerline)
                                    .Within(polygon).RowCount();
```

The error that I receive:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound.
```

The sql actually doesn't bind the parameter (which is the polygon in the query above of type `IGeometry`).

In NHibernate 3.1 a method by the name `GetTypedValues` is called and retrieves the `IGeometry` type of the parameter. In NHibernate 3.3 it is has not been called.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Unless you have managed to figure it out otherwise, I suggest you try with intervening versions, or using git bisect to find the exact commit where the behavior changed. The commit message should then give a clue. Before doing this, you may want to read release notes carefully, or try to find the call to GetTypesValues in the 3.1 source code, then using git blame try to find the commit that changed it.

Comment: This question is older than my son.. but were you using devart oracle driver?